# JSON return sometime normal string and sometime list of string

Tags: c#, json, rest, json.net

I have an external API that returns JSON objects as a response and while I am trying to deserialize it's throwing an exception.

```
public class JsonHoldStringOrListOfString
{
    public static void Main()
    {

        string response = @"{""Response"":{""ResponseStatus"":{""Code"":""1"", ""Description"":""Success""}}, ""SuggestedUserID"":""userId1""}";

        //string response = @"{""Response"":{""ResponseStatus"":{""Code"":""1"", ""Description"":""Success""}}, ""SuggestedUserID"":[""userId1"", ""userId2""]}";


        RootCls result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootCls>(response);
        Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result.SuggestedUserID[0]));
    }
}
```

in one of the responses, `SuggestedUserID` returns as a list, and in another one a normal string, and while returning a normal string it gives an exception while trying to deserialize the `response`.

```
public class Response1
{
    public ResponseStatus1 ResponseStatus { get; set; }
}

public class ResponseStatus1
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class RootCls
{
    public Response1 Response { get; set; }

    [JsonConverter(typeof(ObjectListConverter2<string>))]
    public List<string> SuggestedUserID { get; set; }
}

public class ObjectListConverter2<T> : JsonConverter
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JToken t = JToken.FromObject(value);
        t.WriteTo(writer);
    }

    public override List<T> ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartArray)
        {
            return JToken.Load(reader).ToObject<List<T>>();
        }
        else if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartObject)
        {
            return new List<T> { JToken.Load(reader).ToObject<T>() };
        }
        else if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        throw new JsonException();
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(List<T>) || objectType == typeof(T);
    }
}
```

**Below I am adding the .net fiddle link**
[1]: https://dotnetfiddle.net/G9PbrO

Answer (score 1):

Your custom converter could be this simple:

```
class ArrayOrObjectConverter<T> : JsonConverter
{
    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var token = JToken.Load(reader);
        return token.Type == JTokenType.Array
                ? token.ToObject<List<T>>()
                : new List<T> { token.ToObject<T>() };
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
        => objectType == typeof(List<T>);

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        => throw new NotImplementedException(); 
}
```

- Inside the `ReadJson` first we get a `JToken` to be able to determine the read value's `Type` (kind)

  - Based on that the we can either call `ToObject<List<T>>` or `ToObject<T>`
- Inside the `CanConvert` we examine that the to be populated property's type is a `List<T>`

  - Even though there is a generic `JsonConverter<T>` where you don't have to define the `CanConvert`, its `ReadJson` can be implemented in a bit more complicated way

---

It works fine with both of your inputs: https://dotnetfiddle.net/FqpbcM